# Pycharm link from terminal message error to file

Tags: pycharm

i usually use Pycharm 2019. and now i try to use PyCharm 2020.
One of feature has gone from PyCharm 2019 is link row number code file from terminal message error.

Please explain me how to display it.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\source\django\akun\handlerpy", line 112, in do_set_grup
    hu = HsiUser.objects.using.get(nip=nip)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
[14/Jun/2020 03:02:18] "GET /ajax/?action=set-grup&nip=
```